How are Indirect Question introduced by 'nescio an'? What do they do?
Hope this is alright but my teacher is asking me to research this more but I am super confused and I feel like our grammar book doesn't really go over it.
For nescio an, do we just supply it with a subjunctive? Does it display a  rhetorical sense (such as: I don't know if it works" [I think/doubt it works?])
For instance:

Nescio an melius sit hic manere → I don’t know if it be better to stay here.

Would this become: “I don’t know if its good to be here” or “I think its bad to be here”/”I expect its bad to be here”


Nescio an sit —> I don’t know if it be.
Nescio an currat? → I don’t know if it runs? (rhetorical of: I know it doesn’t run)


Sorry ya'll I am going a little insane trying to grasp what this means. Can you all help?

The Lewis & Short dictionary entry for "an" has literal paragraphs explaining this construction. https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=lsn2407,lsn2409

I am not sure whether I understand your question correctly. Tell me whether I am right. I think it may be several questions. 1.) Is the subjunctive compulsory after nescio an? 2.) Does nescio an have a rhetorical/pragmatic/implied expectation as to whether the subordinate clause shall be false or true? 3.) If so, does this expectation depend upon the presence or absence of the subjunctive?

Since you are tasked with doing research, this answer is more of a guide in helping you, as a direct answer would be too defeating the purpose of the assignment.
First, set aside for a moment the notions of rhetoric or doubt. It's when the subjunctive is the main verb (often called the 'independent' or 'bare subjunctive') that you get the rhetorical, deliberative, jussive, or hortatory uses. But this isn't what's going on here.
There is another set of constructions that could trigger a subjunctive. When there's another main verb, you can find with it dependent clauses with the verb in that clause in the subjunctive mood. Certain keywords will help you figure out what type of clause it is and what the subjunctive is doing there. Furthermore, certain constructions require a subjunctive.
Since clearly nescio is the main verb, you'll need to figure out why there's a subjunctive after it + an.
If you want to do in-depth research (perhaps you have more than a single night), you can peruse Allan and Greenough's Latin Grammar's section on uses of the subjunctive. Pay attention in particular to the dependent clauses sections.
(Hint: You already mentioned "indirect question". Answer this: what is an indirect question? How does it differ from a direct question? This should be your big clue.)
You could do a shorter read by searching around for dependent uses of the subjunctive. I found this site to be decent enough for a quick read.
Make sure too you recognize the function of an in your example. What role does it have? With all of this together, you should be able to piece together why there's a subjunctive after nescio an, but feel free to edit your original question to include your new research if you haven't quite got it.
